Not sure what is causing this system crash
OS Ubuntu 24.04 last updated 15/11/2024. Everything is largely stock. The system is a Dell Optiplex 7070 SFF.
What happens is the mouse cursor turns to a white block in the GUI.This seems to occur when using the default Firefox snap. Then when I go to restart the PC the shutdown sequence gets stuck in this error chain. I have attached the photo. Can you guys point me in the correct direction for where the problem is? The system has a fairly new SSD and a very old secondhand HDD. I have some suspicion this could be the old HDD failing. It reports 2 bad sectors when I formatted it.


Its Ubuntu LTS 24.04.1, I have allowed 3rd party drivers but otherwise everything is default. It was updated a few days ago. The SSD is a Kingston 512gb pcie drive that comes with the Dell Optiplex 7070 SFF (Which is the computer with Ubuntu) I think it's about 6 years old, so not brand new and Ubuntu reports it has the current firmware. I have been messing round with the permissions on the second internal HDD as I am trying to use this PC as my Plex media server. I tried to make the entire directory read write and execute for all users.

This is a hardware issue. You may get around it for the time being, by doing a fsck before the next reboot, but if that works, be sure to backup your sensitive data and don't rely on the hard drive for much longer.

Ok thanks Jos. So is there a way to tell which drive it is? I would like to confirm its the old HDD if possible. I will try to save my movies off it before it fails. They are replaceable, but time is valuable.

As the I/O errors are reported when writing to /var/log... it must be the drive where that folder is located, or probably the whole  / filesystem. To know with certainty which drive/partition that is, in case no partition will boot up, you would need to boot from a live USB system and do something like gparted.

The system restarts and runs fine. So I can seek any information you want from there. I am setting up a bootable USB right now, it seems I may need this for fsck. I have used gparted to partition a drive before, what is the use here? I just need to identify the bad drive, I will by a new drive and transfer the data while it is still alive, as many hours were spent compiling that data and I would rather not do it again.

If the system runs OK, then by all means use that (but I didn't expect that, given that you use the word "crash" in the title). You don't need a separate live system if you want to fsck the root partition: of course you can't initiate a fsck from a running system on its own root partition, but you can force a file system check at the next reboot. Just do sudo touch /forcefsck.

Well the system runs ok but unreliably. It will crash from time to time. I wasn't trying to sound desperate alarm bells with the title crash, I am recently converted from Windows and at least around there we would call this a crash. I just need help with what to do. I want a reliable media server, and right now this PC doesn't make it through most days. I am setting the fsck now with your command. Thank you. The Ubuntu community is just awesome I must say.

Ok. Then first, while the system is running, backup all your stuff. If that doesn't work without I/O errors: reboot, wait for fsck to finish and note carefully whether any blocks are unrecoverable and how many have been recovered. Your system may run more reliably after that (but still do those backups) but there are no guarantees.
